# Command to check graphics device and graphics driver

Tags: 10.10, drivers, command-line, graphics

Is there a utility or terminal command to tell you what graphics device and driver you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, one approach has been documented here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/i810

You can also run this command to locate the device:

`lspci | grep VGA`

If you run the same command with a -k switch, it will give you the driver, too.

`lspci -k`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!